# Information popping up

Tags: html

Hai,
I have seen something that when mouseover is done on a link/word in a HTML page, an information will be popping up.
Can any one post some sample code or link to achieve that.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of 10 plugins, which might be interesting:

- http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/10-excellent-tooltip-plugins-with-jquery/

or - if you want to add tooltips to links - just use the title attribute:

```
<a href="#" title="Hello, Tooltips">Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends entirely on what javascript framework you use.
For instance in jquery, this plugin tooltip(http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/) makes it trivial to do this.

If you are not using any frameworks then use onMouseover etc.
eg

Link

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery QTip to accomplish this.

[Source and examples here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard HTML attributes

```
<img src="path_to_image" title="Information tip about the image"/>
```

Or use JS librery to produce more friendly tooltips

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with a [tooltip plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

[Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) with a [tooltip extension](http://okonet.ru/projects/tooltips/)

Answer (score 0):

To add a tooltip to anything, use the tag [`<acronym>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_acronym.asp), or in [german: (great html reference page)](http://www.selfhtml.net/javascript/objekte/htmlelemente.htm#acronym). Style with css if necessary.